# Read if item is same as JSON item

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

So I am making a discord bot and trying to read the data out of a JSON string when a command is executed. Thing is, my data is not being correctly read and I don't know whats wrong.
Here is my code:

```
@commands.command(aliases=["fg", "chop"])
    async def forage(self, ctx):
        earnings = random.randrange(5)
        await ctx.send(f"You foraged {earnings} logs!")

        users = await self.get_data()
        user = ctx.author
        try:
            bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
        except:
            bag = []
        for item in bag:
            name = item["item"]
            print(item['item'])
            if 'Log' in item["item"]:
                await ctx.send("YES", name)
```

The function get_data just reads the file so nothing interesting is going on there.
This is the JSON file:

```
{"792531381749809174": {"wallet": 40, "bank": 286, "bag": [{"item": "Pickaxe", "amount": 1}, {"item": "Axe", "amount": 2}, {"item": "Log", "amount": 2}]}}
```

The integerstring on the beginning is the users id which is being requested with `users[str(user.id)]` I am trying to check if Log is in the list. the code gives no errors and runs just fine. When I try to print both name and item["item"] they both have Log in them.

Thanks with the help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "my data is not being correctly read"? What are you getting instead of what you expect?

Comment: Are you *expecting* `get_data` to parse the JSON data and create a data structure of nested dicts and lists? Or are you intending to write that code here?

Comment: @Barmar I want to check if Log is in the list.

Comment: What happens when you run the code, and how is that different from what you expect to happen? Is `get_data` your own code or someone else's? If it's someone else's, what does the documentation say about how it works?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What I am trying to do is just check if Log is in the list the code gives no errors and runs just fine. When I try to print both name and item["item"] they both have Log in them.

Comment: `if 'Log' in item["item"]:` will check if `Log` is a substring of the name.

Comment: Please actually answer the questions you are asked. We cannot tell you how to figure out "if Log is in the list" until we ascertain *whether there actually is a list yet*. Please also read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough .

Comment: BTW, why do you keep writing `item["item"]` after you assigned the variable `name`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The list seems to be the value of the `bag` key in the dictionary.

Comment: "the code gives no errors and runs just fine" Then *what actually is the question*? What do you mean when you say "my data is not being correctly read"? *What happens when you run the code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen*?

Comment: @Barmar I was trying to check that the JSON is actually getting parsed correctly. It seems that it is, but now I have no idea what the actual question is.

Comment: Is it not executing `ctx.send("YES", name)`?

Comment: It is, it's a standard function in discord.py

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What I am trying to achieve is to check if Log is in the list. If it is I want it to execute `ctx.send("YES", name)`. But with my current code this does not happen.

Comment: When you say "the code gives no errors and runs just fine", and you also say "with my current code [the thing I want to happen] does not happen", it seems to me that you're contradicting yourself. I can't understand your description of the problem. You should show **exactly** how to use the code, **exactly** what happens, and **exactly** what should happen instead. Don't talk about what doesn't happen; talk about what does and should happen.